# Filter out rows from first match of one pattern until first match of next pattern

Tags: r, regex, filter, dplyr

I have a dataframe with speech data in column `speech`.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c("A", "A", "B", NA, "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
  speech = c("hi", "how are you [Larry]?", "[uh]", "(0.123)", 
             "I'm fine [you 'n Mary] how's it [goin]?", "[erm]", "(0.4)", "well", "y'know what it's like")
)
```

I need to filter out rows that (i) are by the same `id` AND (ii) whose first `speech` value is something in square brackets `[...]`. However, the filter **should not consume all of that same `id`'s speech**: it should stop as soon as the `speech` matches either something in round parentheses `(...)` or simple text.

I can filter the `df` on conditions (i) and (ii):

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(id)) %>% 
  filter(grepl("^\\[.*?\\]$", first(speech)))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   grp [2]
  id    speech                  grp
  <chr> <chr>                 <int>
1 B     [uh]                      2
2 B     [erm]                     5
3 B     (0.4)                     5
4 B     well                      5
5 B     y'know what it's like     5
```

But I don't know how to stop the filter at the `speech` with `(...)` or with text. The **expected outcome** is this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   grp [2]
  id    speech                  grp
  <chr> <chr>                 <int>
1 B     [uh]                      2
2 B     [erm]                     5
```

Help is much appreciated!

**EDIT**:

Seems like I've found a solution myself:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(id)) %>% 
  filter(grepl("^\\[.*?\\]$", first(speech)) & !grepl("^\\(\\d\\.\\d{1}\\)$|^\\w", speech))
```

But thanks anyway to everybody who gave it a thought!

Comment: You don't want the `id == "A"` in the output?

Comment: In the sample data there's no matching row for `A`